# How do i configure tinyproxy to foward traffic to another proxy

Tags: proxy

Is it possible to configure tinyproxy to forward its traffic to another proxy so it looks like

```
                                                 broadcasted through wifi
                                                    /
 *laptop*               *laptop*                   /              *smartphone*  
                                                  /                     |
Firefox traffic <-----> tinyproxy <----> smartphone proxy/other <---> internet
 127.0.0.1:9020              /            192.168.43.1:44355  
                            /           
                           /
                 buffer a high speed response
```

i have managed to set a listening port as **9020** in `/etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf` but its internet connection goes through my regular internet.

Comment: Can you connect your laptop to the Internet via your smartphone's mobile hotspot wifi ?

Comment: its connected through wifi hotspot...but my mobile is also broadcasting a proxy through the wifi that is connectable.

Comment: it could be any type of proxy connection lets say through Ethernet connection..its just for the sake of testing i am using a **proxy server** on my android where i can see the traffic

Comment: You would need to force your 1st proxy to forward all the traffic to the 2nd proxy. Use the Upstream <ipaddress> parameter to forward traffic to your 2nd proxy.

Comment: Upstream http some.remote.proxy:port

Comment: That alone isn't working